# Applying a boundary condition with a different Fourier basis in a wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

Consider a wave equation $$\psi_{tt} - c^2 \psi_{zz} = 0$$ under the bounded domain $-z_0<z<z_0$ and an unbounded domain $t>0$, with the following boundary conditions: $\psi(z,0)=0, \psi(-z_0,t) = \psi(z_0, t)=0$ (fixed end). If I solve this, I get the following expression:

$$\psi(z,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \cos{\frac{(2n-1) \pi z}{2z_o}} \sin{\frac{(2n-1) \pi ct}{2z_o}}$$

If I got the final boundary condition that can be expressed in a Fourier series but under a different basis such that $$\psi_t(z,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \cos{\frac{n \pi z}{z_o}}$$

I can somehow get to the expression of $A_n$ in terms of $B_n$ which was what I intended if I exploit inner products well. But I have a feeling that it's going to be something that's rather complicated. I am wondering if it is just what it is, or the solution I got so far through separation of variables is wrong, or etc.

Comment: The last paragraph isn't clear at all. What is the question? And what is the explicit form of $\psi_{t}(z, 0)$? Also, how did you get the Fourier series in terms of the arbitrary coefficients $A_{n}$? Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @MatthewCassell To clarify, the exact description of the last boundary condition is a constant velocity impulse around the center such that $\psi_t(z,0) = 1 $ for $-\gamma z_0 < z < +\gamma z_0$ and $0<\gamma<1$ and zero otherwise. I confirmed by actually plotting on Matlab that the following real Fourier series is correct: $$\psi_t(z,0) = \gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n \pi} \sin(n\pi \gamma) \cos{\frac{n \pi z}{z_0}}$$

Comment: How can that be the series for $\psi_{t}(z, 0)$ when it doesn't match the form of the derivative in time of your solution $\psi$ evaluated at $t = 0$?

Comment: @MatthewCassell I was asked to use the $\cos(n \pi z / z0)$ form to express the boundary condition. Then you are proposing me to infer that my solution form is probably wrong?

Comment: Well, you have $$\psi(z, t) \sim \cos \frac{(2n-1) \pi z}{2 z_{0}} = \cos \frac{2n \pi z}{2 z_{0}} \cos \frac{\pi z}{2 z_{0}} + \sin \frac{2n \pi z}{2 z_{0}} \sin \frac{\pi z}{2 z_{0}} \ne \cos \frac{n \pi z}{z_{0}} \sim \psi_{t}(z, 0)$$ What happened to the rest of the $z$ terms that were in $\psi$ but aren't in $\psi_{t}$?

Comment: @MatthewCassell But I believe just the cosine without (2n-1) does not satisfy the fixed end boundary conditions? Could you please propose what you think is a correct solution form and is consistent with the BC?